# I dont get any crash count for my windows phone 8 app

Tags: windows-phone-8, crash-reports, marketplace

I have submitted my windows phone 8 app,

There is a option called Reports of our apps in Dashboard of developer account page,

In that we can see the "Crash count " option.

Here i can track my app downloads, but i couldn't see any app crash.

Am i need to add anything specially to update this crash count, like capability.

Can anybody help me.

Thank you.

Comment: `Am i need to add anything specially to update this crash count, like capability.` No, it's automatically enabled. But the end-user must have the "Send feedback" global setting enabled on his phone, or his crash reports won't be sent.

Comment: @KooKiz Hi will the crash count includes the app un install, is there any option to know how many times my app get uninstalled.

Comment: @Noourl A uninstallation isn't a crash, so I don't see why it would be counted. And no, there is no way to track the number of times the app is uninstalled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer, thanks for @KooKiz comments.

No need to add any more extra work, it's automatically enabled. But the end-user must have the "Send feedback" global setting enabled on his phone, or his crash reports won't be sent.

And there is no way to track the number of times the app is uninstalled.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In the Dashboard Reports section you have one option called App Downloads, there you can see the number of times your app has been downloaded over a period of tiem.
In the Crash count report you actually can see the times your app has failed, (a crash). If you don't see anything there... that's good men! your app never do a crash fail. Good Job!

So, if you want to see the downloads go to the "App downloads" report instead of "Crash count"